# Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver ... Window XAMPP MySQL PHP Version => 7.4.4

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've walked through all the StackOverflow answers and no one was useful for my case.

I am on Windows using XAMPP with MySQL my PHP Version is 7.4.4, in my php.ini the extensions are uncommented and I am posting them in here

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll 
extension=php_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

I have done all that all the previous answer said to do, such as uncomment pdo_mysql (which was already uncommented) and I have added a few rows that I am mentioning here again:

```
extension=php_pdo.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll 
extension=php_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

Which were not in the php.ini file but I have added them.

I have looked all around the web and it seems that for having this connection working the only thing to do is to uncomment those few lines and as an extra I have added that .dll reference due to the fact that I couldn't get it to work.

the code which is failing is the following

```
$dbPassword = "admin";
$dbUser = "admin";
$dbServer = "localhost";
$dbName = "PHP";

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbServer.';dbname='.$dbName,$dbUser,$dbPassword);
print_r($connection);
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this driver set properly on windows?

Comment: You have perhaps edited an unused php.ini file. Could you verified it by typing `phpinfo()` in your script. Verify that pdo_mysql is activated. If not, verify the path of the php.ini.

Comment: You are right, I have two php.ini , I was modifiing the one under xampp rather than the one saved in my variable path

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I had two php.ini, one from XAMPP and the other one inside another folder from a previous installation.

Due to the fact that the PATH variable is pointing to the old one, than it wasn't picking my changes.

Fixed via uncommenting the correct php.ini